# Duda sobre bounding boxes SpriteKit

Tags: swift3, spritekit

Como se puede crear una bounding box que colicione con una forma circular, siendo esta triangular?

Comment: A que te refieres con triangular??

Comment: Que la colisión sea contra un objeto con forma triangular, pero no sé cómo ponerle a una bounding box otra forma que no sea circular o rectangular, por ejemplo: un objeto con forma puntiaguda, necesita una forma estrictamente triangular, y no sé cómo colocársela, si me puedes ayudar por favor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Necesitas usar uno del tipo poligonal

```
let polygonalSpaceShip = SKSpriteNode(texture: spaceShipTexture)
let path = CGMutablePath()
path.addLines(between: [CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), CGPoint(x: 50, y: 50), CGPoint(x: 0, y: 50),
                        CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)]) //son 4 porqué el ultimo vuelve al origen
```

Ejemplo de [SKPhysicsBody](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skphysicsbody)

[image: Ejemplo de paths]

Aunque dependiendo de tu sprite puedes intentar usar el alpha channel

```
let texturedSpaceShip = SKSpriteNode(texture: spaceShipTexture)
texturedSpaceShip.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: spaceShipTexture,
                                              size: CGSize(width: circularSpaceShip.size.width,
                                                           height: circularSpaceShip.size.height))
```

Comment: Muchas gracias.